# Creating an air gapped version of bazel but getting an error

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

```
C:\Developers\examples-master\java-tutorial>bazel build --distdir=C:\Developers\bazel-tar //:ProjectRunner
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Repository remotejdk11_win instantiated at:
  no stack (--record_rule_instantiation_callstack not enabled)
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  C:/users/syuopm/_bazel_syuopm/v5bxa2ms/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:336:31: in <toplevel>
WARNING: Download from https://mirror.bazel.build/openjdk/azul-zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6/zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-win_x64.zip failed: class java.io.IOException connect timed out
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'remotejdk11_win':
   java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://mirror.bazel.build/openjdk/azul-zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6/zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-win_x64.zip] to C:/users/syuopm/_bazel_syuopm/v5bxa2ms/external/remotejdk11_win/zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-win_x64.zip: connect timed out
INFO: Repository remote_java_tools_windows instantiated at:
  no stack (--record_rule_instantiation_callstack not enabled)
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  C:/users/syuopm/_bazel_syuopm/v5bxa2ms/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:336:31: in <toplevel>
ERROR: C:/users/syuopm/_bazel_syuopm/v5bxa2ms/external/bazel_tools/tools/jdk/BUILD:492:6: @bazel_tools//tools/jdk:remote_jdk11 depends on @remotejdk11_win//:jdk in repository @remotejdk11_win which failed to fetch. no such package '@remotejdk11_win//': java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://mirror.bazel.build/openjdk/azul-zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6/zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-win_x64.zip] to C:/users/syuopm/_bazel_syuopm/v5bxa2ms/external/remotejdk11_win/zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-win_x64.zip: connect timed out
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:ProjectRunner' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 68.089s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (16 packages loaded, 305 targets configured)
```

Comment: Please mention the question details also. Only logs will not help in understanding the problem.

Comment: Hi Anshu, I am trying to create an airgapped verion of bazel and using the -distdir option. Most packages are being loaded execpt zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-win_x64.zip. Please advice of any solutions

Answer (score 0):

A Possible work around is to fetch the files of zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-win_x64.zip  manually and put them in a directory specified via the `--distdir` option. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/6196#issuecomment-441193202) and Usually this happens due to network or proxy issues.